# Como crear 2 clusters de Nifi con un servidor zookeeper

Tags: java, apache, nodos, cluster, zookeeper

Cómo puedo crear 2 cluster con un solo servidor zookeeper externo, tengo 5 máquinas dónde quiero tener 2 cluster de 2 nodos de nifi con un zookeeper externo que gestione los 2 cluster.

En configuración de zookeeper en el archivo zoo.cfg no eh cambiado nada, solo lo copie del zoo de ejemplo y para un cluster me funciona correctamente.

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
```

De esta forma me llega a funcionar normal un cluster

Dónde en los nodos de nifi están configurados para apuntar a ese servidor con el puerto 2181.

```
nifi.cluster.node.address=node1
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=zookeeper.example.com:2181
nifi.web.http.host=node1.example.com
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.cluster.protocol.port=11443
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=3
```

Cómo está configuración están todos mis nodos, para 2 cluster intenté cambiando el nifi.cluster.protocol.port=
A un puerto diferente en 2 nodos pero igual siguen uniéndose al anterior cluster y no forman otro, reinicie todas las máquinas y el resultado es el mismo.